# The hold_position or Hold_position doesn't work in kableExtra?

Tags: html, r, kableextra

I use kableExtra package to create some html format files.

And I use hold_position to change the caption location but it doesn't work.

The reproducible code below came from the kableExtra package official samples:

```
kbl(dt, caption = "Demo table", booktabs = T) %>%
kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "hold_position"))
```

My result like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your output is html, you could add `<center>text<\center>` to your caption:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)

kbl(mtcars, caption = "<center>Demo table</center>", booktabs = T) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = "striped")
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Oh,sorry. I forget it. Thanks,it works well.